# Ubuntu 14.04 won't boot after installation

Tags: dual-boot, 14.04, system-installation, windows-7

Here's the story, I have windows 7 on my Pc and I just installed Ubuntu 14.04, here's how I've done it:

1. Went in Windows and made some unallocated space in order to install ubuntu there.
2. Installed ubuntu there using the something else method ( I have made a ext4 partition for ubuntu and a swap partition ).
3. Everythings done I restart.

Problem is, now that I have installed it I can't access it.When my pc boots up it directly boots in windows and also in it's boot options there is none that could boot me into Ubuntu.

I've seen some solutions using boot-repair and such but they don't seem to work anymore in 14.04.

So how can I make it to Dual-Boot both Windows and Ubuntu ?

***Update***

Due to the fact that I have installed ubuntu from an USB I tried the following lines:

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sdX
sudo update-grub
```

I used sd4 ( the place where I installed Ubuntu ) instead of sdX.Sadly after the first line it gave me the follwing error : "Failed to get the canonical path of '/cow' "

---

I have tried the possible duplicate solution and here's what I get.

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo mount /dev/sd4 /mnt
mount: special device /dev/sd4 does not exist
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo mount /dev/sda4 /mnt
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo mount /dev/sda4 /mnt/boot
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo grub-install --root-directory=/mnt /dev/sda4
Installing for i386-pc platform.
grub-install: warning: File system `ext2' doesn't support embedding.
grub-install: warning: Embedding is not possible.  GRUB can only be installed in     this setup by using blocklists.  However, blocklists are UNRELIABLE and their use is discouraged..
grub-install: error: will not proceed with blocklists.
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo grub-install --root-directory=/mnt /dev/sda4
Installing for i386-pc platform.
grub-install: warning: File system `ext2' doesn't support embedding.
grub-install: warning: Embedding is not possible.  GRUB can only be installed in this setup by using blocklists.  However, blocklists are UNRELIABLE and their use is discouraged..
grub-install: error: will not proceed with blocklists.
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo grub-install /dev/sda4
Installing for i386-pc platform.
grub-install: error: failed to get canonical path of `/cow'.
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$
```

Sda4 is a Ext4 partition however so I don't understand why it sais Ext2.

Answer (score 1):

After you boot with USB, you need to mount the / partion (the easiest way is using nautilus) and use chroot

```
sudo chroot /media/ubuntu/drivename
```

Then you can issue the grub update

```
 sudo grub-install /dev/sda4
 sudo update-grub
```

Answer (score 0):

Grub seemingly isn't configured right, the process for dual boot when you start up is that it goes to grub and then you choose. So your grub has some trouble.

When you install the 14.04, did it tell you to put the bootloader (grub, in this case) in a special partition called EFI? I am wondering where your grub is stored.